# InfluxDB Line Protocol Performance 1.8 vs. 2.0

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, influx-line-protocol

I noticed that there is a considerable (5x) performance penalty when upgrading my app from InfluxDB 1.8 to 2.0. I'm using ILP and the only change I made on the ingress side was switching from `/write` to `/api/v2/write`, adding the auth token and org and bucket query parameters. I am writing 25,000 data points per second in bursts of 100 data points using 10 connections in parallel. My laptop runs at ~18% with 1.8 and ~94% with 2.0.

Is this an expected behavior? Maybe some default database performance settings changed?

Comment: We haven't observed write performance degradation in 2.1, but we are generally using larger batches of 1000 up to 5000 points. Did not try 2.0.

Comment: I would also suggest trying much larger batches to see if that helps. You may also need to review your index type configuration